# Como montar modelos para o GLM no R

Tags: r, glmer

Gostaria de fazer um GLM com as seguintes variáveis:

**Variável resposta:** EVI

**Variáveis independentes:** % de floresta, densidade de borda, numero de fragmentos, temperatura e precipitação.

Alguém poderia gentilmente me ajudar a montar os modelos, não faço ideia de como proceder.

Comment: O que é EVI? Que tipo de variável é essa?

Comment: É um índice de vegetação José, ele varia de 0.1 a 1. Utilizo ele como proxy da produtividade vegetal.

Comment: Por que você usaria glm no lugar de lm? Essa variável EVI não é contínua?

Answer (score 2):

Existem vários pacotes para ajustar modelos lineares generalizados (GLM) no R. Entretanto, as pessoas provavelmente utilizam mais a própria função `glm` que já vem no R base.

Para ajustar um modelo usando a função `glm` você precisa passar a fórmula do modelo, a família da distribuição que você quer ajustar (por exemplo, `binomial` para dados binários, `poisson` para dados de contagem, `gaussian` para o modelo linear tradicional e assim por diante) juntamente com o link (por exemplo, `probit`, `logit` ou `cloglog` para `binomial`). Se você não especificar o link o R vai usar o default para a distribuição escolhida.

Vamos ver um exemplo com a regressão logística. Simulando uns dados de exemplo:

```
set.seed(10)
x <- rnorm(1000)
prob <- plogis(-2*x)
y <- rbinom(1000, 1, prob)
```

E agora ajustando o modelo:

```
glm(y ~ x, family = binomial(link = logit))
Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x, family = binomial(link = logit))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   -0.01969     -1.94726  

Degrees of Freedom: 999 Total (i.e. Null);  998 Residual
Null Deviance:      1386 
Residual Deviance: 931.9    AIC: 935.9
```

Outros pacotes que avançam em modelos lineares generalizados são o [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) para `glm` com penalização (L1, L2 ou ambas), o [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) para modelos `glm` com efeitos mistos, [vgam](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html) para vector generalized linear models.

Então para começar você tem que ter uma ideia de qual (quais) modelo(s) você quer ajustar e seguir mais ou menos as ideias esboçadas acima. No seu caso, sua fórmula seria algo como EVI ~ % de floresta + densidade de borda + número de fragmentos + temperatura + precipitação etc ou outra forma funcional mais adequada... entretanto, explicar qual a forma funcional que você tem que adotar, ou qual a distribuição ou link você tem que escolher é algo específico que envolve estatística e conhecimento substantivo do seu problema e foge ao escopo do StackOverflow.